# Wrap each word with a tag inside a sentence with Python regex and `re.sub`

Tags: python, regex

I want to split the sentence into words, wrap words in tags and join the string back.

Example: `Test, abc; text.`. Should become `<span>Test</span>, <span>abc</span>; <span>text</span>.`

I've tried to use regex and `\b` but I don't understand how `\b` works.

Comment: It is ``re.sub(r'\w+', r'<span>\g<0></span>', text)``

Comment: Will it work with all letters (Chinese, German) etc.?

Comment: Yes, in Python 3. In Python 2.x, you'd need to add `flags=re.U`. Or just `re.sub(r'(?u)\w+', r'<span>\g<0></span>', text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
text = "Test, abc; text."
print( re.sub(r'\w+', r'<span>\g<0></span>', text) )
# => <span>Test</span>, <span>abc</span>; <span>text</span>.
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/NzOwzU).

With `\w+`, you match any chunks of one or more letters, digits, some diacritical marks or connector punctuation chars and the `<span>\g<0></span>` replacement pattern wraps each match (`\g<0>` is the whole match backreference) with span tags.

Note that, in Python 3, `\w` matches any Unicode letters and digits. In Python 2.x, you'd need to add `flags=re.U`:

```py
re.sub(r'\w+', r'<span>\g<0></span>', text, flags=re.U)
```

Or use an inline modifier:

```py
re.sub(r'(?u)\w+', r'<span>\g<0></span>', text)
```